# Data is loading after binding in template angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

After some manipulation on data, I am getting response in console like this:

```
[{"date":"02-01-2018 - 31-12-2018"},{"date":"01-07-2018 - 31-12-2018"}]
```

But when I am trying to display this value in drop down, nothing is showed, its seems data binding happens before data loading. kindly help

Here is my code

```
Change(opened: boolean) {
    if (opened) { }     
    var rvaldata:any= [];

    calculateRange(this.choosenSub);
    if(rvaldata!='')
    {
    this.nrvaldata=JSON.stringify(rvaldata);
    console.log(this.nrvaldata);
    }
    function calculateRange(_data){
    var r = "";
    for(var i=0;i<_data.length;i++){
       var isArray = Array.isArray(_data[i]);
       if(isArray){
        r+=calculateRange(_data[i]);
       }else{
        var x = _data[i].date;
        r = rvaldata.push({'date':x})
        }
      }
      return JSON.stringify(r);
      }  
}
```

Here is my html

```
<div  class="d-inline-block">
<span class="plabel">Date<span class="star">*</span></span>
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="Validity" class="project-tab" [formControl]="toppings" multiple required>
<ng-template >
<mat-option *ngFor="let t of nrvaldata; let i = index" [value]="t.date">{{t.date}}</mat-option>
</ng-template>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Kindly help

Comment: post your code.

Comment: I have updated my question, kindly help

Comment: `nrvaldata` is not an array, because your calling `JSON.stringify` on the data...

Comment: how to display its value on template, kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*ngFor` expects an array, but because you're calling `JSON.stringify` you're actually passing it a string. If you check in the browsers console you will probably see an error about this.

Just replace

```
this.nrvaldata=JSON.stringify(rvaldata);
```

with

```
this.nrvaldata=rvaldata;
```

Also, remove the `ng-template` tags and you should find it will work.

[Here is a StackBlitz of it in action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wu4ez5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I have updated my code, but in drop down is still not showing value, probably data binding before data loading, kindly help

Comment: @mjck Just updated the answer. You need to remove the `ng-template` tags from your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is the `<ng-template>` directive `ng-template`s are like function they are not executed unless called in other words they are not displayed unless you call *ngIf="true" to them or  use them for a template to other container using expression.

Remove the ng-template around `mat-option`

```
<div  class="d-inline-block">
<span class="plabel">Date<span class="star">*</span></span>
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="Validity" class="project-tab" [formControl]="toppings" multiple required>
<mat-option *ngFor="let t of nrvaldata; let i = index" [value]="t.date">{{t.date}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```